# Gazebo model rotating itself

Tags: gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I am new at Gazebo simulation. I define rotation axis in my model but my model is rotating itself (at wrong axis) that makes my robotic arm model really funny.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2210/gazebo-model-rotating-itself/) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-03**:
Could you post your sdf file, and be a bit more explicit about the problem? Cheers

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-03**:
Thanks Andrei. Problem is solved by changing revolution type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I used revolute2 rotation type instead of revolute so when collision cloud collides it starts moving in other random directions.
Problem is sovled now =)

---

Originally posted by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) with karma: 131 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0